# How to test for thrown error with Chai.should

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, chai

I'm using [Chai.should](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) and I need to test for an exception, but whatever I try, I cannot get it to work. The [docs](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_throw) only explain `expect` :(

I have this Singleton class which throws an error if you try

```
new MySingleton();
```

Here is the constructor that throws the error

```
constructor(enforcer) {
    if(enforcer !== singletonEnforcer) throw 'Cannot construct singleton';
    ...
```

Now I would like to check that this happens

```
 it('should not be possible to create a new instance', () => {
    (function () {
        new MySingleton();
    })().should.throw(Error, /Cannot construct singleton/);
 });
```

or

```
new MySingleton().should.throw(Error('Cannot construct singleton');
```

None of these work. How is this done ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. It is asking about the `subject.should.throw` style. The other question is for the `expect` style.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Problem here is that you are executing the function directly, effectively preventing chai from being able to wrap a `try{} catch(){}` block around it.

The error is thrown before the call even reaches the `should`-Property.

Try it like this:

```
 it('should not be possible to create a new instance', () => {
   (function () {
       new MySingleton();
   }).should.throw(Error, /Cannot construct singleton/);
});
```

or this:

```
MySingleton.should.throw(Error('Cannot construct singleton');
```

This lets Chai handle the function call for you.

Comment: Just want to add, if anyone is looking to pass parameters to the function, you can do `myfunc.bind(foo, bar).should.throw(...)`.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an answered question, but i'd still like to throw in my two cents.

There is a section in the style guide for this, namely: http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should-extras. So what does this look like in practice:

```
should.Throw(() => new MySingleton(), Error);
```

It's not all that different from the accepted answer, i find it a bit more readable though, and more in line with their guideline.

Comment: I believe this is the way to go, so I would mark this as accepted to help people.
This is much more like chai style, I liked it.
Especially when it comes to argument passing, this way is way more cleaner.